# Modern syntax for old-fashioned Keras command "Convolution2D"?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was studying different CNN architectures to predict the CIFAR10 dataset, and I found this interesting Github repository:

https://gist.github.com/wielandbrendel/ccf1ff6f8f92139439be

I tried to run the model, but it was created in 6 years ago and the following Keras command is no longer valid:

> model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, 3, border_mode='full'))

How is this command translated into the modern Keras syntax for `Conv2D`?

I get an error in Keras when I try to input the sequence of integers in `Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, 3, ...)`?
I guess `32` is the number of channels, and then we specify a `3x3` kernel size, but I am not sure about the meaning of the last `3` mentioned (4th position).

PS. Changing `border_mode` into `padding = 'valid'` or `'same'` returns the following error:

```
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, 3, padding='valid'))
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'padding'
```

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D

Comment: Hi @NicolasGervais , thank you for your message. I tried looking at the Keras documentation, but I am not sure about the meaning of the last `3` passed as arguments to the code. Please let me know if you are familiar with the meaning of this 4th argument.

Comment: @C-3PO let me know if you've any queries regarding the given answer.

Comment: @M.Innat Thanks for the answer, the code works indeed. I will let you know if I have any questions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gist` there you're following is backdated and also has some issues. You don't need to follow this now. Here is the updated version of it. Try this.

**Imports and DataSet**

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Dense, Dropout, Activation, 
                                    Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D)
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adadelta, Adagrad
import tensorflow as tf 

# parameters
batch_size = 32
nb_classes = 10
nb_epoch = 5

# the data, shuffled and split between tran and test sets
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes) 
Y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

# train model
X_train = X_train.astype("float32") / 255
X_test = X_test.astype("float32") / 255

X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape
((50000, 32, 32, 3), (50000, 1), (10000, 32, 32, 3), (10000, 1))
```

**Modeling**

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                 strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                 strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                 strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# let's train the model using SGD + momentum (how original).
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Compile and Run**

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch)

# test score & top 1 performance
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
y_hat = model.predict(X_test)
yhat = np.argmax(y_hat, 1)
top1 = np.mean(yhat == np.squeeze(y_test))

print('Test score/Top1', score, top1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Convolutional2D` is now named `Conv2D`, but there is still an alias for `Convolutional2D`, so that's not a problem.

The `border_mode` argument is not available anymore, the equivalent is `padding`, with options `valid` or `same`.

Try both to see if any of those fits the shapes of the outputs and allows to code to work.

Comment: Hi @dataista, thank you for your help. I tried to apply the changes you mentioned, but I got the following error:
`model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, 3, padding='valid'))`
`TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'padding'`

I think the issue is that passing 4 integers as arguments is not valid anymore. Please let me know if you know the original meaning of this sequence of integers. I guess it means something like, 32 channels, 3x3 kernel, and then an extra 3 for something...